# java: if statement which skips the following if statement

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, arraylist, continue

I have a 2D-String-array through which I am going row by row to find the minimum. When I found the minimum I am adding the row of the found minimum to an ArrayList to skip the row in the next iteration to find the second lowest number of the Array. I am doing this until every row number is part of the ArrayList.

See my code so far:

```
List assignedRow = new ArrayList();    
for(int t = 0; t < excelMatrix.length-1; t++){    
double lowest = Double.parseDouble(excelMatrix[0][1]);
    int row = 0, column = 0;    

    for(int r = 0; r < excelMatrix.length-1; r++){                      
        if(assignedRow.contains(r) == true) continue;               
        for(int c = 1; c < excelMatrix[r].length; c++){             
            double value = Double.parseDouble(excelMatrix[r][c]);
            if(lowest > value) {
                lowest = value;
                row = r;    
                column = c; 
            }   
        }   
    } 
    assignedRow.add(row);
}
```

The code works fine so far, until the minimum is in row 0. Afterwards it is always executing the continue condition.

I am now looking for something which allows me to go back into the for loop, using the next higher r which is not part of the ArrayList.

I hope I made my problem clear.

Comment: Just a side note (it's not the problem): `if(assignedRow.contains(r) == true)` is just a long way to write `if(assignedRow.contains(r))`. `contains` *already* returns a `boolean`, you don't need to use `== true` to get one. I mean, where do you stop? `if((assignedRow.contains(r) == true) == true)` ? `if(((assignedRow.contains(r) == true) == true) == true)` ? **;-)**

Comment: I'm afraid I can't quite understand what it is you want to do.

Comment: `if(assignedRow.contains(r) == true)` will only skip those rows which already has the minimum. Problem will arise if minimum & 2nd minimum are in the same row

Comment: @T.J.Crowder he wants to find the minimum in the `2D` array, followed by the second lowest number and so on, but ignoring the rows he already found one (that´s what i got from this question)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the problem is that if the lowest value is in row 0, 0 is inside the ArrayList and so the rest of the for loop is not executed. I always need to know the lowest value of one row, the rest of the values in this row are irrelevant, which is why I am skipping them. But if for example the first minimum is in row 0, I am not able to find any other minimums in the array, because it always exectues "continue".

Comment: @KevinEsche that is right.

Comment: @boersencrack check my answer. I have updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work.

```
  List assignedRow = new ArrayList();
    double lowest = 0;
    while (assignedRow.size() < excelMatrix.length) {

        // find intial lowest value from non assign row to compare
        for (int t = 0; t < excelMatrix.length - 1; t++) {
            if (!assignedRow.contains(t)) {
                lowest = Double.parseDouble(excelMatrix[t][0]);
                break;
            }
        }

        int row = 0, column = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < excelMatrix.length - 1; r++) {
            if (assignedRow.contains(r)) continue;
            for (int c = 0; c < excelMatrix[r].length; c++) {
                double value = Double.parseDouble(excelMatrix[r][c]);
                if (lowest > value) {
                    lowest = value;
                    row = r;
                    column = c;
                }
            }
        }
        assignedRow.add(row);
    }
```

Your code will not work if lowest value is stored at first column of any row because you are start iterating from column index 1 (third for loop `int c=1` and `lowest = Double.parseDouble(excelMatrix[0][1]`)